# How can I modify my CSL code to display author names in all uppercase?

Tags: citations, csl

Is it possible to change the code so the name will be all uppercase?
When I add a text-case="uppercase" (or lowercase or anything) it changes nothing, even though I am in the correct block - if I have font-weight or something else, it changes correctly.
My current CSL code looks like this:

```
<macro name="author">
    <names variable="author" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="none" vertical-align="baseline">
      <name font-variant="normal" font-weight="normal" delimiter-precedes-last="never" initialize-with=". " name-as-sort-order="all"/>
      <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=")"/>
      <et-al font-style="italic"/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <names variable="translator"/>
        <choose>
          <if type="article-newspaper article-magazine" match="any">
            <text variable="container-title" text-case="title" font-style="italic"/>
          </if>
          <else>
            <text macro="title"/>
          </else>
        </choose>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
```

If I give an example how it looks:
**Campbell, J. L., Pedersen, O. K. (2007)**: The varieties of capitalism and hybrid success, Comparative Political Studies, 40(3), 307–332. https://doi.org/10.1177/0010414006286542.
What I would like to get:
**CAMPBELL, J. L., PEDERSEN, O. K. (2007)**: The varieties of capitalism and hybrid success, Comparative Political Studies, 40(3), 307–332. https://doi.org/10.1177/0010414006286542.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `text-case="uppercase"` on an explicit `name-parts` element, like so:

```
<macro name="author">
    <names variable="author">
      <name delimiter-precedes-last="never" initialize-with=". " name-as-sort-order="all">
        <name-part name="family" text-case="uppercase"/>
      </name>
      <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=")"/>
      <et-al font-style="italic"/>
      <substitute>
        ...
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
```

You don't actually have your code with uppercase in the question, but I suspect you had it set on either `name` or `names`, which [isn't allowed as per the specification](https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#text-case).